# Controlling a Lego WeDo 2.0 Motor using Python in Ubuntu

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy, lego-mindstorms

I am trying to control the motor of a Lego Wedo 2.0 set via `Python` from an ubuntu distribution.

The Lego WeDo 2.0 "hub" uses a bluetooth low energy technology, and to it, a motor is connected via cable, that I want to spin.

I read a lot about the specific BLED112 USB dongle, which is [also recommended by Lego](https://education.lego.com/de-de/support/wedo-2/bluetooth-driver), but I currently just have a generic Bluetooth 4.0 USB dongle. `hci0` is the dongle, and  `hci1` the internal one.

The command `sudo hcitool -i hci0 lescan` shows, when the motor is in pairing mode, the output `A0:E6:F8:49:E2:93 LPF2 Smart Hub 2 I`. Then,

`gatttool -I
[                 ][LE]> connect A0:E6:F8:49:E2:93` throws "connection successful".

My Python code is now:

```
from gattlib import GATTRequester
from time import sleep

address = 'A0:E6:F8:49:E2:93'

req = GATTRequester(address,True,"hci0")
req.write_by_handle(0x3d, "\x06\x04\x01\x09")
sleep(2)
req.write_by_handle(0x3d, "\x01\x01\x01\x64")
sleep(2)
req.write_by_handle(0x3d, "\x01\x01\x01\x9C")
sleep(2)
req.write_by_handle(0x3d, "\x01\x01\x01\x00")
```

which should change the color of the [engine's LED](https://ofalcao.pt/blog/2016/wedo-2-0-colors-with-python), and [spin it a bit](https://www.ev3dev.org/docs/tutorials/controlling-wedo2-motor/), then stop.

However, the only output I receive is:

`RuntimeError: connect: Device or resource busy (16)`

when using `hci1` instead, the dongle flashes quickly for a few seconds, then the error appears:

`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Finally, when I disconnect the dongle and type `hci0` in the above code, the error is: `RuntimeError: Invalid device!`, as I would expect, given that the dongle has been removed.

During all of this, the WeDo engine just shows a constant blue light, indicating that it is connected and waiting for orders.

In the code `req.write_by_handle(0x3d, "\x01\x01\x01\x64")`, the initial `\x01` should dictate which port of the WeDo-Hub the motor is connected to, and it is indeed connected to the first port. (Anyway, the first command would address the hub itself, to change its colors, so even if the motor was connected to the wrong port, the colors should change nonetheless.)

What am I missing?

I do have access to a Windows PC with Lego's children-friendly software on it, which successfully pairs with and controls the motor.

Are there any other models for electric motors that can be perhaps more easily controlled via Python? Both USB or Bluetooth would be fine.

---

Running

```
from gattlib import GATTRequester, GATTResponse, DiscoveryService
from time import sleep

service = DiscoveryService("hci0")
devices = service.discover(2)

for address, name in devices.items():
    print("name: {}, address: {}".format(name, address))
```

gives as output:

```
name: LPF2 Smart Hub 2 I, address: A0:E6:F8:49:E2:93
```

Next,

```
from gattlib import GATTRequester

req = GATTRequester("A0:E6:F8:49:E2:93")
name = req.read_by_uuid("00002a00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb")[0]
steps = req.read_by_handle(0x15)[0]
```

outputs:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: ***`gattlib`***: Do you have any reference, that `gattlib` can be used on **Ubuntu** or do you have a public link to it?

Comment: I have no reference on gattlib and ubuntu, but there was no error during install. Would you recommend using another package?
Here is a link to gattlib: https://pypi.org/project/gattlib/

Comment: Read, try and show the output, if any, from: [Discovering devices](https://bitbucket.org/OscarAcena/pygattlib/src/default/#markdown-header-discovering-devices). Obey the **Note:** about `sudo` but try also without.

Comment: [Edit] your question and show the output of: `pip3 show python3-gattlib` and `import sys ; print(sys.version)`

Comment: `pip3 show python3-gattlib` does not give any output. I installed `gattlib` using `sudo pip install gattlib`, which confirmed that `gattlib` is installed. 

The directory [...] is not owned by the current user and the cache (and caching wheels) has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting gattlib
  Downloading https://.../gattlib-0.20150805.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: gattlib
  Running setup.py install for gattlib ... done
Successfully installed gattlib-0.20150805

Comment: ***"I installed gattlib using `sudo pip install gattlib`"***: So my second requested output, about `sys.version`. becomes important. What about my request about [Discovering devices](https://bitbucket.org/OscarAcena/pygattlib/src/default/#markdown-header-discovering-devices)?

Comment: ***"(are you root)?"***: Did `sudo python3 <your Discovering devices py>` succeed?

Comment: yes, it succeeded after restart. I have updated the question with the output from Discovering Devices.

The output of the other queries is:

3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02) 
[GCC 8.3.0]

Comment: ***"other queries is: 3.6.9 "***: This makes any `pip install ...` useless. You are running Python 3.x therefore you have to do `pip3 install ...` instead. Retry with `pip3 install python3-gattlib`.

Comment: `pip3 install python3-gattlib` gives `404 Client Error: Not found for url: https://pypi.org/simple/python3-gattlib/`.

However, `sudo pip3 install gattlib` gives "Requirement already satisfied: gattlib in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205229/discussion-between-stovfl-and-marie-p).